# Using wkhtmltoimage from wkhtmltopdf

Tags: wkhtmltopdf, wkhtmltoimage

I read in their documentation that `wkhtmltoimage` is inside `wkhtmltopdf`, so I installed `wkhtmltopdf` using apt-get, because that's the only way I could get all dependencies working.

Now I can use `wkhtmltopdf`, but when I use `wkhtmltoimage`, I keep getting that command was not found.

Why is that so? How can I use it?

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
wkhtmltoimage --width=750 'http://google.com/' test.jpg
```

Comment: What does `wkhtmltopdf --version` output for you? The versions that you get with apt-get can be ancient. I suggest that you download it manually

Comment: Yup, that was the case, apt-get downloaded old version :D

Comment: Oh! Well, I guess sometimes guesses can hit their target :D

Comment: Where is is documented ? Official documentation in http://wkhtmltopdf.org/ clearly states that wkhtmltopdf converts only to pdf

Answer (score 1):

What does wkhtmltopdf --version output for you? The versions that you get with apt-get can be ancient. I suggest that you download it manually